# Search for the previous elements from the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with tracking the index from the list. I want to search to get the previous elements from the list. If I have two elements in the list, I would like to find the 5 previous elements so I can store them in the list.

Example: When the variable `start_ch` show the two elements in the list `'421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2'`, I want to fetch the 5 previous elements of `'416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV'` to store them in the list that joins the two last elements.

I want to make it to show like this:

```
['416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
```

Here is what `start_ch` show when I am fetching the two elements:

```
['421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
```

Here is the list for `self.channel`:

```
 ['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ', '407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK', '414 Eurosport 2 UK', '415 BT Sport 1', '416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
```

When I try this:

```
for i, start_ch in enumerate(self.channel):
    if start_ch == channel:
        start_ch = self.channel[i:i+7]

        if len(start_ch) == 1:
           start_ch = self.channel[i:i-6]
        elif len(start_ch) == 2:
           start_ch = self.channel[i:i-5]
        elif len(start_ch) == 3:
           start_ch = self.channel[i:i-4]
        elif len(start_ch) == 4:
           start_ch = self.channel[i:i-3]
        elif len(start_ch) == 5:
           start_ch = self.channel[i:i-2]
        elif len(start_ch) == 6:
           start_ch = self.channel[i:i-1]
        print "start_ch"
        print start_ch

        for channels in start_ch:
           print "channels_list"
           channels_list.append(channels)  #add chanel to list
           print channels_list
```

It will not let me to fetch the 5 previous elements from the list apart from the last two elements.

Can you please show me an example how I can fetch the previous 5 elements from the list apart from the two last elements so I can join them together to store them in the list?

Comment: But it is unclear how the result should look like when start_ch is ['416 BT Sport 2', '422 Eir Sport 2'] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this (may be):

```
>>> channel = ['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ', '407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK', '414 Eurosport 2 UK', '415 BT Sport 1', '416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
>>> to_find = ['421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
>>> target_index = self.channel.index(to_find[0])
>>> result = channel[target_index-5:target_index] + to_find
>>> result
['416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV','421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
```